# Duplicate print job to multiple printers on OS X

Tags: macos, printing, network-printer, cups

I'm trying to create a printer set-up which allows me to print a document, and have it printed by the same printer twice, using 2 different trays. So I'm looking for a solution that will print the entire document with the paper in tray 1, and then print it again using tray 2.

I already have configured two printers on the machine (OS X):

- `Printer A` - Prints on Physical Printer 1, Tray 1
- `Printer B` - Prints on Physical Printer 1, Tray 2

So far so good. The next step would be to define a `Printer C` as far as I'm correct, which forwards its print job to `Printer A` and `Printer B`.

- I'm reading things about CUPS Printer Classes, but I cannot get those configured as I wish. It seems like it selects only one printer of the pool instead of both.
- I'm also reading things about defining a printer which [uses a shell script](http://aplawrence.com/Unixart/dual_print.html) - but that results in my case in one page printed with the print job name (from the first tray), and another page from the second tray (as expected).

Who can help me out?

Comment: You don't need a Printer C to do this. Shell script will do. Share the script you have used and hopefully i can get it solved.

Answer (score 0):

you can either print to a shell script ([examples](https://wiki.alienbase.nl/doku.php?id=slackware:cups)), which duplicates the job (that virtual `Printer C`) ...

or create a "prehook" with [Tea4CUPS](http://www.pykota.com/software/tea4cups), which executes just before the job gets inserted into the printing queue - there probably is no other way to control what happens, in this situation.